# Error free(): double free detected in tcache 2

Tags: c++, map

Cuando hago un insert con un `make_pair` a un `map` me devuelve el siguiente error:

> free(): double free detected in tcache 2
>
> Abortado (`core' generado)

La línea es la siguiente:

```
tarjetas_.insert(std::make_pair(t.numero(), &t));
```

Asumo que los valores que le paso son correctos porque cuando no lo son devuelve otro error diciendo que son incorrectos.

`tarjetas_` es un mapa así:

```
std::map<Numero, Tarjeta*>
```

Y la función donde se usa es ésta:

```
void Usuario::es_titular_de(Tarjeta& t){

    std::map<Numero, Tarjeta*>::const_iterator i = tarjetas_.find(t.numero());
    if(this == t.titular() && i == tarjetas_.end()){
        tarjetas_.insert(std::make_pair(t.numero(), &t));
    }
}
```

Comment: Por un lado, decirte que necesitamos más código para poder reproducir tu problema. Por otro lado, no me convencen los datos que introduces en el mapa. La direccion de memoria que contiene `t` dejará de tener datos válidos en cuando finalice la llamada a dicha función. Lees el mapa así: `std::map<Numero, Tarjeta*>`, pero insertas en él así: `std::map<Numero, Tarjeta**>`, ya que `t` ya es un puntero a `Tarjeta`, no necesitas obtener un puntero a dicho puntero con `&`. Si no me equivoco (a falta de poder probar tu código), deberías usar `tarjetas_.insert(std::make_pair(t.numero(), t));`.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Además, para poder reproducir tu problema y encontrar una solución fácilmente nos sería de gran ayuda un **[ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**. Necesitamos el código mínimo necesario para reproducir tu problema. Gracias.

Comment: Voto el cierre por no haber aportado más información cinco días después de la publicación.